# Mysql select the last 5 added and make them rand

Tags: php, mysql

what im tryng to do is select the last 5 order by viewtime and from that 5 selected to make a rand and to give me 1

example if i select viewlast: 56789, 56788, 56787, 56786, 56785 to give me rand of this 5 numbers 1, lets say this 56788 or this 56786

**Update**

```
$Last_Video         = $db->fetch_all("select VID, thumb FROM video WHERE title LIKE '%" . $Channel['name'] . "%' ORDER BY viewtime DESC limit 5");
```

this was the command what i use before

Comment: You tagged this question with both php and mysql. You want this in mysql only or as some php code? Please specify.

Comment: im was thinking to make it with mysql command just but php is oky to

Answer (score 3):

Take the last 5 and then order by RAND():

```
$query = '
    SELECT VID, thumb
    FROM video
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT VID
        FROM video
        WHERE title LIKE "%'.$Channel['name'].'%"
        ORDER BY viewtime DESC
        LIMIT 5)
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
';
```

Comment: like this ? SELECT VID, thumb from video WHERE title IN ( SELECT VID, thumb FROM video ORDER BY viewtime DESC LIMIT 5) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 but i use this command to before WHERE title LIKE '%" . $Channel['name'] . "%'

Comment: The subquery needs to return 1 column. You probably want the id (primary key) for that. Your subquery returns two columns. Of course you need the primary query to filter on the same column that the subquery returns.

Comment: i update the post the command what i use before ... hope you can help me fix this

Comment: i try the code but is give me this error "MySQL Error: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"

Comment: Change it into an INNER JOIN with the subquery. MySQL also optimizes joins better than `IN (SELECT...)`.

Comment: Or just use Ahmed Habib's answer

Comment: @Barmar: as always, there's more than one solution for a problem. Ahmed Habibs answer will probably also work. Any discussion about query optimizing should start with the `LIKE` clause. The wildcard `%` as start character means that MySQL cannot use any index for that search.

Comment: @MihaiViteazu: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 5.1.59 this is the version what i use

Comment: In that case you should go for Ahmed Habibs answer, or update your MySQL server version, (or both).

Answer (score 1):

It might help you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM <#TABLE> ORDER BY viewtime DESC LIMIT 5
) AS TBL 
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Change `<#TABLE>` with table name.

Comment: This will show the **first** five entries. The right way to do it is by ordering in descending order: `ORDER BY viewtime DESC` (I just added it)